# How can I make an title like this?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

So... I want to make a title like this:

[image]

But the problem is when I try to make it, the bigger text of the title just doesn't stay close from the others, and the left-border does not fit with the top of "Pablo" and the bottom of "CG SUPERVISOR...":

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>
        <span class="span1">Pablo</span><br>
        <span class="span2">Emmanuel De Leo</span><br>
        <span class="span3">CG Supervisor / TD / Tool Development</span>
    </h1>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

h1 .span1 {
    font-size: 100px;
}

h1 .span2 {
    font-size: 34.3px;
    line-height: 0;
}

h1 .span3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

By the way... I tried it for myself, and I got it, but for responsive It's so annoying to adaptate and I don't think it's is a very good idea make this title like this...

Here is the other code:

HTML

```
FONT:
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Hat+Text:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    <div class="header-title-container">
        <div class="header-intro"></div>
        <div class="header-title">
            <h1>
                <span>Pablo</span>
                <span>Emmanuel De Leo</span>
            </h1>
            <h3>CG Supervisor / TD / Tool Development</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.header-title-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header-title-container .header-title {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Red Hat Text', sans-serif;
}

.header-title-container .header-title h1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.header-title-container .header-title h1 span:first-child {
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.header-title-container .header-title h1 span:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 3px;
    font-size: 23.8px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.header-title-container .header-title h3 {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.header-title-container .header-intro {
    width: 5px;
    height: 98px;
    background-color: red;
    align-self: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can get some ideas out of this: https://jsfiddle.net/h8xug4c3/1/

Comment: @JoãoPauloMacedo Wow, good idea, thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div>`s rather than `<span>`s, that will allow you to control line heights and margins separately for each of the three lines.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fred {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.fred>*:first-child {
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}

.fred>*:nth-child(2)  {
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fred>*:last-child {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fred">
        <div>Pablo</div>
        <div>Emmanuel De Leo</div>
        <div>CG Supervisor / TD / Tool Development</div>
    </h1>
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, thank u so much! But... the problem es when you want to make it responsive, because the left-border just doesn't grow with the title...

Comment: Um, I think you'll find it does. If you make the snippet full page and then use responsive design mode to switch to a phone view, as the text wraps around onto additional lines, the red border does grow to match.